# Error with matlabprefs.mat when starting Matlab 2017B

Tags: matlab, startup

When I start matlab, it welcomes me with this message. I just installed Matlab 2017B, but I was also having this issue before with another version of Matlab (2016A, I believe) on a Dell PC running Windows 7 Professional. Does anyone know what it means or, more importantly, how to resolve it?

Warning: Initializing MATLAB Graphics failed.
This indicates a potentially serious problem in your MATLAB setup, which should be resolved as soon as possible.
Error detected was:
MATLAB:load:unableToReadMatFile
Unable to read MAT-file C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2017b\matlabprefs.mat. File might be corrupt.

> In hgrc (line 163)
>     In initprefs (line 11)
>     In matlabrc (line 124)

I quickly plotted plot(1,1) and the window comes up, so it doesn't seem to be immediately affecting my ability to create graphics, even though it is a graphics error.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same error recently.

The `matlabprefs.mat` file consisted of 12KB of zero-bytes. Removing it (actually I renamed it to `matlabprefs.mat.broken`, just in case) and starting MATLAB again resulted in a clean startup with no error messages.

There doesn't seem to be any official documentation of this, and I am not a MathWorks employee. So *everything that follows is speculation*.

---

**What happened?**

Well, if your situation is the same as mine then what happened is that the matlabprefs file was corrupted, and MATLAB noticed and complained.

In my case, the most likely cause of the corruption is that my computer was abruptly powered down a few days ago with MATLAB running; perhaps MATLAB had the file open and this is enough to cause bad things to happen.

**What does it mean?**

I don't know what is usually stored in matlabprefs.mat, but after removing it and restarting MATLAB there is exactly one thing in mine, namely a note of my current working directory. (So that MATLAB can start up with the right working directory next time.)

I *don't* think it contains the preferences you can set in the MATLAB GUI; those appear to be in a file called `matlab.prf` in the same directory. (Maybe also in `matlab.settings`, also in the same directory.) So you probably haven't lost anything important.

The warning message talks about graphics, so perhaps in some circumstances the file contains information about (e.g.) recent figure window settings. I would be extremely surprised if it contained anything super-important.

**What should you do?**

I would suggest that you exit MATLAB, delete the `matlabprefs.mat` file named in the error message, and restart MATLAB. If you are feeling ambitious you could rename the file instead and open it up in a text editor or something, and see if there's anything in there that might be informative to you.

My guess is that you will suffer no long-term adverse consequences.